# SP SQL maintenance - as logs is growing

Tags: sql-server

Should there be a process in place to shrink the log and the db for sp databases? I noticed some of the log files are in GBs.

Should the db in Full or simple mode? Are there any standard or good practice for sp sql maintenance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a a white paper on SharePoint DB maintenance which does cover shrinking.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24282

Comment: Correct link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/cc262731(v=office.14)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Full mode in Production, Simple mode on Dev

Longer answer: It depends on your requirements. Setting your databases to simple recovery greatly reduces your disaster recovery options. Normally, on a production environment you will have SQL database backups in place, which automatically cause the transaction logs to be trimmed so the growth should not become such an issue. It is not good practice to manually shrink/truncate them on a production environment (it means you have no proper DB backup process).

On development servers (and often staging, QA, etc.) where there is no database backup, your transaction logs will grow until your disk is filled up if you don't manage them. I have not seen enterprise settings where development machines were required to have disaster recovery plans on their SP content database so I always set those to Simple mode. Specifically, the SP_Config transaction log grows very quickly and is a good candidate for Simple mode. As long as your development artefacts (source code) are backed up, you should not need to worry much.